# Laravel Wildcard Routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to create a wildcard route to host multiple domains. It works as long as I don't use a country specific domain name.

```
Route::group([
    'domain' => 'admin.{domain}.{tld}',
    'namespace' => 'Admin\Pages'
], function () {
    require base_path('routes/web/admin/pages.php');
});
```

The main area to look at `'domain' => 'admin.{domain}.{tld}'`

This works for domains on a single extension, eg. `domain.com` but it does not work for domains with a country code eg. `domain.com.au`. What is the wildcard for catching both the tld and country code so that both domains will work and not just one.

This example works for instance `'domain' => 'admin.{domain}.com.au'` but is not dynamic.

Comment: When using both wildcards, what is the value of the `tld`? null? empty string? also, which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.4

{tld} == .com OR .org  (etc)

Comment: and the value of `domain`?

Comment: It is a wildcard. So it will be "example" if the domain is "example.com"

Comment: Obviously it is a wildcard as we're talking about domain wildcards here. Are the values set, is anything null, undefined, empty string? What exactly is the output? Worst case is, you need to build a middleware that injects the country code to the request. Or use a filter with regex to check for country code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I worked it out.

`admin.{domain}.{tld}.{cc}`

It doesn't matter what they are named as long as their is enough periods to catch all of the extensions. They get saved to variables such as $domain, that can be used inside the closures.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens with a domain like `example.com` (which doesn't have a country code?

Comment: From my limited testing it looks to just be ignored. I have tested for both .com and .com.au with and without subdomains and they all seem to work fine.